# My Laptop running at 89% memory use?! - Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, memory

It's been a while that my computer has been running at a very high ram usage when i have nothing running...please help i will provide all possible information. I have a MSI GE60 laptop.

[image]

[image]

I don't know why there is 9 chrome.exe running when i have 6 tabs on chrome open only.
I have tried stopping some services and looking into what is taking the most usage but i cant find it at all.

Comment: Extensions run as separate processes in Chrome so the 3 extra processes should be some extensions you have enabled.

Comment: But do you know why its using 7.2 GB out of 8.0 Gb when i have nothing too big opened except for chrome.

Comment: Something other than Chrome is eating your RAM. Just look through all the processes and spot the culprit.

Comment: i tried looking at each, nothing so far.

Comment: Chrome uses a separate process for each tab.

Answer (score 5):

You have a memory leak caused by a driver. Look at the high value of nonpaged kernel memory. In your case this is over 5 GB.

[image]

You can use [poolmon](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2012/08/30/troubleshooting-pool-leaks-part-2-poolmon.aspx) to see which driver is causing the high usage.

Install the [Windows WDK](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=317353), run poolmon, sort it via <kbd>P</kbd> after pool type so that non paged is on top and via <kbd>B</kbd> after bytes to see the tag which uses most memory.

Now look which pooltag uses most memory as shown here:

[image]

Now open a cmd prompt and run the findstr command to see which driver uses this tag:

[image]

Now look at the file properties, find the driver version and look for an update.

Comment: Hey i appreciate this help..i will try it once I'm home but recently I've used malmarebytes and ran a full scan it quarantined 29 items mostly dealply stuff and after a restart memory stays at 25% but i would love to use these steps u posted because there is a chance it can happen again right? I just want to be safe for the future and to avoid researching so much again :/

Answer (score -1):

This is a issue with the nonpaged RAM pool, not Chrome issue.

---

Edit:

General help with Chrome and high RAM usage: http://www.techverse.net/how-to-troubleshoot-google-chromes-high-cpu-memory-usage/

Of course, if not Chrome is the one using so much RAM, you should probalby check if your PC is infected with a virus

Answer (score -1):

One person mentioned a memory leak.  When was the last time you shut down and then powered up (not restart).  That will clear any memory that was not released upon closing of a program.